# WPF List selection issue when opening files

Tags: wpf, popup, process.start

Got a WPF application which has an on hover popup. The popup contains a list of different files which can be opened (e.g. pdf, excel etc)

You can navigate and select a file by double clicking and it opens as you would expect.

But if I now navigate to a different file I can see that the on hover selection isn't now working,

If you now select a different file, the original file is opened again.

I am using a Process.Start and passing the full path to the file to the method.

The application is a fair size so here are some excerpts for a Test application I have written to look into this further

The XAML for the main window

```
<Window x:Class="TestPopupIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Canvas Margin="5" Background="Red" Width="200" Height="150" >

        <Rectangle Name="rectangle1"
           Canvas.Top="60" Canvas.Left="50"
           Height="85" Width="60" 
           Fill="Black" MouseEnter="rectangle1_MouseEnter"   MouseLeave="rectangle1_MouseLeave"  />

        <Popup x:Name="PopupWindow" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=rectangle1}" Placement="Top"  MouseEnter="rectangle1_MouseEnter"  MouseLeave="rectangle1_MouseLeave">
            <ListBox MinHeight="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" MouseDoubleClick="FileList_MouseDoubleClick"`enter code here` x:Name="FileList" />
        </Popup>
    </Canvas>


</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        FileList f;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            f = new FileList();
            f.PopulateFiles();

            this.DataContext = f;
        }

        private void FileList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileList.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string item = FileList.SelectedItem as string;

                if (item != null)
                {
                   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(item);               
                }

            }
        }

        private void rectangle1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PopupWindow.IsOpen = true;
        }

        private void rectangle1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PopupWindow.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

And there is a FileList class which just has a generic string list of file paths called 
Files

Thanks

Comment: Why are you firing the same MouseEnter and MouseLeave on both controls?  I think you need to simplify that somehow.

Comment: Its just for simplicity for this sample - the original has fades etc. Here, when you leave the rectangle the popup closes when you hover over it without the other mouseenter

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your Sample-Application, when your opening the File with Process.Start your Focus gets stolen by the Application that opens your File.
Somehow the ListBox in the Popup can´t change their SelectedItem when the Window has lost his Focus.

Unfortunately I have not managed to get the focus back on the Window, this.SetFocus() has not worked for me.

Anyway another possible Solution would be to close the Popup when your opening the File.

```
private void FileList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (FileList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string item = FileList.SelectedItem as string;

        if (item != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(item);
            PopupWindow.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }       
}
```

this way the ListBox can update the selectedItem again.

hope this helps!